# Docker image to access docker container from browser

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I would like to create a docker image that fires browser and inside browser should be able to run docker daemon. For example: https://www.katacoda.com/courses/docker/2.

Can someone please put in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The example is not running docker inside the browser. Its a service that is running on a set of machines that have docker. The commands get transfered to a machine and are executed there.

The service also provides a web interface which is just for the user to enter the commands. The browser doesn't have anything to do with Docker.

The most popular example for such services is the [docker playground](http://labs.play-with-docker.com/). The docker playground is opensource and you can see the code [here](https://github.com/play-with-docker/play-with-docker) to get some ideas.